# Can't connect to GitLab CI/CD mongodb replica set service with alias

Tags: mongodb, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, mongodb-memory-server

I created a MongoDB replicaset docker image for testing purposes. It uses *mongodb-memory-server* open source project (which is a MongoDb with in memory storage). See https://gitlab.com/sunnyatticsoftware/mongodb-rs

I also created a repo with a GitLab CI/CD pipeline to test connectivity to MongoDb, which uses the above docker image as a GitLab CI/CD service, it assigns to it an alias `mongors` and uses the connection string `mongodb://mongors:27017?replicaSet=rs0`. See https://gitlab.com/sunnyatticsoftware/mongodb-rs-tester

It can be tested locally with

```
docker run --name mongodbrs -p 27017:27017 registry.gitlab.com/sunnyatticsoftware/mongodb-rs
```

And connecting to `mongodb://localhost:27017?replicaSet=rs0` or to `mongodb://mongors:27017?replicaSet=rs0` (same as the CI/CD pipeline) if there is an entry in /etc/hosts file pointing `mongors` to `127.0.0.1`

The problem is when I run the same in GitLab CI/CD (shared runner in GitLab.com). For some reason, it can't connect to the  MongoDb instance. With other services I never encounter any problem referring to the alias to reach the hostname, but with this one it seems there is an issue with connectivity. Why? How to allow [this pipeline](https://gitlab.com/sunnyatticsoftware/mongodb-rs-tester/-/jobs/5319052214) to succeed?

```
[xUnit.net 00:00:30.68]     MongoDbConnection.FunctionalTests.ConnectorTests.It_Should_Connect_To_Replica_Set_Database [FAIL]
  Failed MongoDbConnection.FunctionalTests.ConnectorTests.It_Should_Connect_To_Replica_Set_Database [30 s]
  Error Message:
   System.TimeoutException : A timeout occurred after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = ReadPreferenceServerSelector{ ReadPreference = { Mode : Primary } }, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 }, OperationsCountServerSelector }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode : "ReplicaSet", Type : "ReplicaSet", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "127.0.0.1:27017" }", EndPoint: "127.0.0.1:27017", ReasonChanged: "Heartbeat", State: "Disconnected", ServerVersion: , TopologyVersion: , Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server.
...
```

---

**UPDATE 1**

I created a different tester project for GitLab CI/CD to leave the C# Mongo Driver out of the picture and use mongosh instead
Here it is https://gitlab.com/sunnyatticsoftware/mongodb-rs-tester-mongosh

The CI/CD pipeline fails. Log here https://github.com/nodkz/mongodb-memory-server/files/13051684/raw_log_pipeline.txt

Things I found

Locally, with the same docker container, the connection string

```
mongodb://mongors:27017?replicaSet=rs0
```

connects well
In GitLab CI/CD, if I use the connection string

```
mongodb://mongors:27017 it pings OK, but mongodb://mongors:27017?replicaSet=rs0
```

fails (see logs)
The command I run in pipeline is

```
mongosh "mongodb://mongors:27017?replicaSet=rs0" --quiet --eval "db.runCommand({ ping: 1 })" || exit 1
```

as per my [.gitlab-ci.yml](https://gitlab.com/sunnyatticsoftware/mongodb-rs-tester-mongosh/-/blob/main/.gitlab-ci.yml?ref_type=heads)

---

**UPDATE 2**

I created an [issue](https://github.com/nodkz/mongodb-memory-server/issues/815) here to investigate, because I don't think it's a connectivity issue. It looks like it can find the host/alias but the connection is rejected when specifying replica set. See the following log where, in addition to showing `/etc/hosts`, I try to connect to

- `mongosh "mongodb://mongors:27017" --quiet --eval "db.runCommand({ ping: 1 })" || exit 1` **OK**
- `mongosh "mongodb://mongors:27017?replicaSet=rs0" --quiet --eval "db.runCommand({ ping: 1 })" || exit 1` **ERROR**

```
$ mongosh --version
2.0.2
$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.3  registry.gitlab.com__sunnyatticsoftware__mongodb-rs 398338eeb54b runner-ns46nmmj-project-51414559-concurrent-0-e41c37375e72e41f-registry.gitlab.com__sunnyatticsoftware__mongodb-rs-0
172.17.0.3  registry.gitlab.com-sunnyatticsoftware-mongodb-rs 398338eeb54b runner-ns46nmmj-project-51414559-concurrent-0-e41c37375e72e41f-registry.gitlab.com__sunnyatticsoftware__mongodb-rs-0
172.17.0.3  mongors 398338eeb54b runner-ns46nmmj-project-51414559-concurrent-0-e41c37375e72e41f-registry.gitlab.com__sunnyatticsoftware__mongodb-rs-0
172.17.0.4  runner-ns46nmmj-project-51414559-concurrent-0

$ echo "Connect mongosh to mongodb://mongors:27017"
Connect mongosh to mongodb://mongors:27017
$ mongosh "mongodb://mongors:27017" --quiet --eval "db.runCommand({ ping: 1 })" || exit 1
[service:registry.gitlab.com__sunnyatticsoftware__mongodb-rs-registry.gitlab.com-sunnyatticsoftware-mongodb-rs-mongors] 2023-10-21T20:48:48.268613610Z 2023-10-21T20:48:48.268Z MongoMS:MongoInstance Mongo[27017]: stdoutHandler: ""{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-21T20:48:48.268+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"172.17.0.4:55660","uuid":"2a8e7616-78df-4b99-99e6-85c58352c0eb","connectionId":4,"connectionCount":1}}""
[service:registry.gitlab.com__sunnyatticsoftware__mongodb-rs-registry.gitlab.com-sunnyatticsoftware-mongodb-rs-mongors] 2023-10-21T20:48:48.272056363Z 2023-10-21T20:48:48.271Z MongoMS:MongoInstance Mongo[27017]: stdoutHandler: ""{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-21T20:48:48.271+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn4","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"172.17.0.4:55660","client":"conn4","doc":{"application":{"name":"mongosh 2.0.2"},"driver":{"name":"nodejs|mongosh","version":"6.0.0|2.0.2"},"platform":"Node.js v20.8.1, LE","os":{"name":"linux","architecture":"x64","version":"5.4.109+","type":"Linux"}}}}""
[service:registry.gitlab.com__sunnyatticsoftware__mongodb-rs-registry.gitlab.com-sunnyatticsoftware-mongodb-rs-mongors] 2023-10-21T20:48:48.286567180Z 2023-10-21T20:48:48.286Z MongoMS:MongoInstance Mongo[27017]: stdoutHandler: ""{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-21T20:48:48.286+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"172.17.0.4:55662","uuid":"dd86bb85-3095-4003-ac6e-759bdbd5ee73","connectionId":5,"connectionCount":2}}
[service:registry.gitlab.com__sunnyatticsoftware__mongodb-rs-registry.gitlab.com-sunnyatticsoftware-mongodb-rs-mongors] 2023-10-21T20:48:48.286589530Z {"t":{"$date":"2023-10-21T20:48:48.286+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"172.17.0.4:55664","uuid":"f878666f-a628-445f-b06f-5f4f9464c5f2","connectionId":6,"connectionCount":3}}""
[service:registry.gitlab.com__sunnyatticsoftware__mongodb-rs-registry.gitlab.com-sunnyatticsoftware-mongodb-rs-mongors] 2023-10-21T20:48:48.287491289Z 2023-10-21T20:48:48.287Z MongoMS:MongoInstance Mongo[27017]: stdoutHandler: ""{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-21T20:48:48.287+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn5","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"172.17.0.4:55662","client":"conn5","doc":{"application":{"name":"mongosh 2.0.2"},"driver":{"name":"nodejs|mongosh","version":"6.0.0|2.0.2"},"platform":"Node.js v20.8.1, LE","os":{"name":"linux","architecture":"x64","version":"5.4.109+","type":"Linux"}}}}""
[service:registry.gitlab.com__sunnyatticsoftware__mongodb-rs-registry.gitlab.com-sunnyatticsoftware-mongodb-rs-mongors] 2023-10-21T20:48:48.288369637Z 2023-10-21T20:48:48.288Z MongoMS:MongoInstance Mongo[27017]: stdoutHandler: ""{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-21T20:48:48.288+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn6","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"172.17.0.4:55664","client":"conn6","doc":{"application":{"name":"mongosh 2.0.2"},"driver":{"name":"nodejs|mongosh","version":"6.0.0|2.0.2"},"platform":"Node.js v20.8.1, LE","os":{"name":"linux","architecture":"x64","version":"5.4.109+","type":"Linux"}}}}""
[service:registry.gitlab.com__sunnyatticsoftware__mongodb-rs-registry.gitlab.com-sunnyatticsoftware-mongodb-rs-mongors] 2023-10-21T20:48:48.296276792Z 2023-10-21T20:48:48.296Z MongoMS:MongoInstance Mongo[27017]: stdoutHandler: ""{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-21T20:48:48.296+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"172.17.0.4:55666","uuid":"529da4a0-1ddf-4d87-b4fc-ed56c1d3f9be","connectionId":7,"connectionCount":4}}""
[service:registry.gitlab.com__sunnyatticsoftware__mongodb-rs-registry.gitlab.com-sunnyatticsoftware-mongodb-rs-mongors] 2023-10-21T20:48:48.297127200Z 2023-10-21T20:48:48.297Z MongoMS:MongoInstance Mongo[27017]: stdoutHandler: ""{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-21T20:48:48.296+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn7","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"172.17.0.4:55666","client":"conn7","doc":{"application":{"name":"mongosh 2.0.2"},"driver":{"name":"nodejs|mongosh","version":"6.0.0|2.0.2"},"platform":"Node.js v20.8.1, LE","os":{"name":"linux","architecture":"x64","version":"5.4.109+","type":"Linux"}}}}""
{
  ok: 1,
  '$clusterTime': {
    clusterTime: Timestamp({ t: 1697921325, i: 1 }),
    signature: {
      hash: Binary.createFromBase64("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=", 0),
      keyId: Long("0")
    }
  },
  operationTime: Timestamp({ t: 1697921325, i: 1 })
}
$ echo "Connect mongosh to mongodb://mongors:27017?replicaSet=rs0 (notice the replicaSet parameter)"
Connect mongosh to mongodb://mongors:27017?replicaSet=rs0 (notice the replicaSet parameter)
$ mongosh "mongodb://mongors:27017?replicaSet=rs0" --quiet --eval "db.runCommand({ ping: 1 })" || exit 1
[service:registry.gitlab.com__sunnyatticsoftware__mongodb-rs-registry.gitlab.com-sunnyatticsoftware-mongodb-rs-mongors] 2023-10-21T20:48:48.555348507Z 2023-10-21T20:48:48.555Z MongoMS:MongoInstance Mongo[27017]: stdoutHandler: ""{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-21T20:48:48.554+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn5","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"172.17.0.4:55662","uuid":"dd86bb85-3095-4003-ac6e-759bdbd5ee73","connectionId":5,"connectionCount":2}}
[service:registry.gitlab.com__sunnyatticsoftware__mongodb-rs-registry.gitlab.com-sunnyatticsoftware-mongodb-rs-mongors] 2023-10-21T20:48:48.555404277Z {"t":{"$date":"2023-10-21T20:48:48.554+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn7","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"172.17.0.4:55666","uuid":"529da4a0-1ddf-4d87-b4fc-ed56c1d3f9be","connectionId":7,"connectionCount":1}}
[service:registry.gitlab.com__sunnyatticsoftware__mongodb-rs-registry.gitlab.com-sunnyatticsoftware-mongodb-rs-mongors] 2023-10-21T20:48:48.555413937Z {"t":{"$date":"2023-10-21T20:48:48.554+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn4","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"172.17.0.4:55660","uuid":"2a8e7616-78df-4b99-99e6-85c58352c0eb","connectionId":4,"connectionCount":0}}
[service:registry.gitlab.com__sunnyatticsoftware__mongodb-rs-registry.gitlab.com-sunnyatticsoftware-mongodb-rs-mongors] 2023-10-21T20:48:48.555420517Z {"t":{"$date":"2023-10-21T20:48:48.554+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn6","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"172.17.0.4:55664","uuid":"f878666f-a628-445f-b06f-5f4f9464c5f2","connectionId":6,"connectionCount":3}}""
[service:registry.gitlab.com__sunnyatticsoftware__mongodb-rs-registry.gitlab.com-sunnyatticsoftware-mongodb-rs-mongors] 2023-10-21T20:48:48.950560737Z 2023-10-21T20:48:48.950Z MongoMS:MongoInstance Mongo[27017]: stdoutHandler: ""{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-21T20:48:48.950+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"172.17.0.4:55668","uuid":"261247c9-9600-4006-a558-1bd88230adaf","connectionId":8,"connectionCount":1}}""
[service:registry.gitlab.com__sunnyatticsoftware__mongodb-rs-registry.gitlab.com-sunnyatticsoftware-mongodb-rs-mongors] 2023-10-21T20:48:48.954180531Z 2023-10-21T20:48:48.954Z MongoMS:MongoInstance Mongo[27017]: stdoutHandler: ""{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-21T20:48:48.953+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn8","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"172.17.0.4:55668","client":"conn8","doc":{"application":{"name":"mongosh 2.0.2"},"driver":{"name":"nodejs|mongosh","version":"6.0.0|2.0.2"},"platform":"Node.js v20.8.1, LE","os":{"name":"linux","architecture":"x64","version":"5.4.109+","type":"Linux"}}}}""
[service:registry.gitlab.com__sunnyatticsoftware__mongodb-rs-registry.gitlab.com-sunnyatticsoftware-mongodb-rs-mongors] 2023-10-21T20:48:48.960618122Z 2023-10-21T20:48:48.960Z MongoMS:MongoInstance Mongo[27017]: stdoutHandler: ""{"t":{"$date":"2023-10-21T20:48:48.960+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn8","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"172.17.0.4:55668","uuid":"261247c9-9600-4006-a558-1bd88230adaf","connectionId":8,"connectionCount":0}}""
MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

So **the problem seems to be related to the** `?replicaSet=rs0` parameter (which works well locally, of course). Why?

---

**UPDATE 3**

Sending `{hello:1}` instead of `{ping:1}` has similar outcome where the replica set is refusing the connection

```
$ echo "Connect mongosh to mongodb://mongors:27017"
Connect mongosh to mongodb://mongors:27017
$ mongosh "mongodb://mongors:27017" --quiet --eval "db.runCommand({ hello: 1 })" || exit 1
[service:mongors-registry.gitlab.com__sunnyatticsoftware__mongodb-rs-registry.gitlab.com-sunnyatticsoftware-mongodb-rs] 2023-11-02T10:03:03.638200491Z 2023-11-02T10:03:03.637Z MongoMS:MongoInstance Mongo[27017]: stdoutHandler: ""{"t":{"$date":"2023-11-02T10:03:03.637+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"172.17.0.4:33342","uuid":"6cd2028d-b1b3-492f-964f-178d7059c9df","connectionId":4,"connectionCount":1}}""
[service:mongors-registry.gitlab.com__sunnyatticsoftware__mongodb-rs-registry.gitlab.com-sunnyatticsoftware-mongodb-rs] 2023-11-02T10:03:03.648909609Z 2023-11-02T10:03:03.648Z MongoMS:MongoInstance Mongo[27017]: stdoutHandler: ""{"t":{"$date":"2023-11-02T10:03:03.648+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn4","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"172.17.0.4:33342","client":"conn4","doc":{"application":{"name":"mongosh 2.0.2"},"driver":{"name":"nodejs|mongosh","version":"6.0.0|2.0.2"},"platform":"Node.js v20.8.1, LE","os":{"name":"linux","architecture":"x64","version":"5.4.109+","type":"Linux"}}}}""
[service:mongors-registry.gitlab.com__sunnyatticsoftware__mongodb-rs-registry.gitlab.com-sunnyatticsoftware-mongodb-rs] 2023-11-02T10:03:03.664107471Z 2023-11-02T10:03:03.663Z MongoMS:MongoInstance Mongo[27017]: stdoutHandler: ""{"t":{"$date":"2023-11-02T10:03:03.663+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"172.17.0.4:33344","uuid":"845d59ee-fb66-4898-bd38-98d14cdb8b5c","connectionId":5,"connectionCount":2}}
[service:mongors-registry.gitlab.com__sunnyatticsoftware__mongodb-rs-registry.gitlab.com-sunnyatticsoftware-mongodb-rs] 2023-11-02T10:03:03.664138321Z {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-02T10:03:03.663+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"172.17.0.4:33346","uuid":"329d6499-e234-4d12-ab8c-e57d77756190","connectionId":6,"connectionCount":3}}""
[service:mongors-registry.gitlab.com__sunnyatticsoftware__mongodb-rs-registry.gitlab.com-sunnyatticsoftware-mongodb-rs] 2023-11-02T10:03:03.665336594Z 2023-11-02T10:03:03.665Z MongoMS:MongoInstance Mongo[27017]: stdoutHandler: ""{"t":{"$date":"2023-11-02T10:03:03.665+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn5","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"172.17.0.4:33344","client":"conn5","doc":{"application":{"name":"mongosh 2.0.2"},"driver":{"name":"nodejs|mongosh","version":"6.0.0|2.0.2"},"platform":"Node.js v20.8.1, LE","os":{"name":"linux","architecture":"x64","version":"5.4.109+","type":"Linux"}}}}""
[service:mongors-registry.gitlab.com__sunnyatticsoftware__mongodb-rs-registry.gitlab.com-sunnyatticsoftware-mongodb-rs] 2023-11-02T10:03:03.665876761Z 2023-11-02T10:03:03.665Z MongoMS:MongoInstance Mongo[27017]: stdoutHandler: ""{"t":{"$date":"2023-11-02T10:03:03.665+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn6","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"172.17.0.4:33346","client":"conn6","doc":{"application":{"name":"mongosh 2.0.2"},"driver":{"name":"nodejs|mongosh","version":"6.0.0|2.0.2"},"platform":"Node.js v20.8.1, LE","os":{"name":"linux","architecture":"x64","version":"5.4.109+","type":"Linux"}}}}""
[service:mongors-registry.gitlab.com__sunnyatticsoftware__mongodb-rs-registry.gitlab.com-sunnyatticsoftware-mongodb-rs] 2023-11-02T10:03:03.673855875Z 2023-11-02T10:03:03.673Z MongoMS:MongoInstance Mongo[27017]: stdoutHandler: ""{"t":{"$date":"2023-11-02T10:03:03.673+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"172.17.0.4:33348","uuid":"88427e09-d6f5-4f8c-bd2b-82562305ede9","connectionId":7,"connectionCount":4}}""
[service:mongors-registry.gitlab.com__sunnyatticsoftware__mongodb-rs-registry.gitlab.com-sunnyatticsoftware-mongodb-rs] 2023-11-02T10:03:03.675417506Z 2023-11-02T10:03:03.675Z MongoMS:MongoInstance Mongo[27017]: stdoutHandler: ""{"t":{"$date":"2023-11-02T10:03:03.675+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn7","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"172.17.0.4:33348","client":"conn7","doc":{"application":{"name":"mongosh 2.0.2"},"driver":{"name":"nodejs|mongosh","version":"6.0.0|2.0.2"},"platform":"Node.js v20.8.1, LE","os":{"name":"linux","architecture":"x64","version":"5.4.109+","type":"Linux"}}}}""
{
  topologyVersion: {
    processId: ObjectId("654373bbc2a9bcf5f306fc06"),
    counter: Long("6")
  },
  hosts: [ '127.0.0.1:27017' ],
  setName: 'rs0',
  setVersion: 1,
  isWritablePrimary: true,
  secondary: false,
  primary: '127.0.0.1:27017',
  me: '127.0.0.1:27017',
  electionId: ObjectId("7fffffff0000000000000001"),
  lastWrite: {
    opTime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1698919376, i: 1 }), t: Long("1") },
    lastWriteDate: ISODate("2023-11-02T10:02:56.000Z"),
    majorityOpTime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1698919376, i: 1 }), t: Long("1") },
    majorityWriteDate: ISODate("2023-11-02T10:02:56.000Z")
  },
  maxBsonObjectSize: 16777216,
  maxMessageSizeBytes: 48000000,
  maxWriteBatchSize: 100000,
  localTime: ISODate("2023-11-02T10:03:03.962Z"),
  logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: 30,
  connectionId: 7,
  minWireVersion: 0,
  maxWireVersion: 17,
  readOnly: false,
  ok: 1,
  '$clusterTime': {
    clusterTime: Timestamp({ t: 1698919376, i: 1 }),
    signature: {
      hash: Binary.createFromBase64("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=", 0),
      keyId: Long("0")
    }
  },
  operationTime: Timestamp({ t: 1698919376, i: 1 })
}
[service:mongors-registry.gitlab.com__sunnyatticsoftware__mongodb-rs-registry.gitlab.com-sunnyatticsoftware-mongodb-rs] 2023-11-02T10:03:03.976117734Z 2023-11-02T10:03:03.975Z MongoMS:MongoInstance Mongo[27017]: stdoutHandler: ""{"t":{"$date":"2023-11-02T10:03:03.975+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn6","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"172.17.0.4:33346","uuid":"329d6499-e234-4d12-ab8c-e57d77756190","connectionId":6,"connectionCount":2}}""
[service:mongors-registry.gitlab.com__sunnyatticsoftware__mongodb-rs-registry.gitlab.com-sunnyatticsoftware-mongodb-rs] 2023-11-02T10:03:03.976528782Z 2023-11-02T10:03:03.976Z MongoMS:MongoInstance Mongo[27017]: stdoutHandler: ""{"t":{"$date":"2023-11-02T10:03:03.975+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn5","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"172.17.0.4:33344","uuid":"845d59ee-fb66-4898-bd38-98d14cdb8b5c","connectionId":5,"connectionCount":3}}
[service:mongors-registry.gitlab.com__sunnyatticsoftware__mongodb-rs-registry.gitlab.com-sunnyatticsoftware-mongodb-rs] 2023-11-02T10:03:03.976564302Z {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-02T10:03:03.975+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn4","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"172.17.0.4:33342","uuid":"6cd2028d-b1b3-492f-964f-178d7059c9df","connectionId":4,"connectionCount":1}}
[service:mongors-registry.gitlab.com__sunnyatticsoftware__mongodb-rs-registry.gitlab.com-sunnyatticsoftware-mongodb-rs] 2023-11-02T10:03:03.976574112Z {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-02T10:03:03.976+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn7","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"172.17.0.4:33348","uuid":"88427e09-d6f5-4f8c-bd2b-82562305ede9","connectionId":7,"connectionCount":0}}""
$ echo "Connect mongosh to mongodb://mongors:27017?replicaSet=rs0 (notice the replicaSet parameter)"
Connect mongosh to mongodb://mongors:27017?replicaSet=rs0 (notice the replicaSet parameter)
$ mongosh "mongodb://mongors:27017?replicaSet=rs0" --quiet --eval "db.runCommand({ hello: 1 })" || exit 1
[service:mongors-registry.gitlab.com__sunnyatticsoftware__mongodb-rs-registry.gitlab.com-sunnyatticsoftware-mongodb-rs] 2023-11-02T10:03:04.421868163Z 2023-11-02T10:03:04.421Z MongoMS:MongoInstance Mongo[27017]: stdoutHandler: ""{"t":{"$date":"2023-11-02T10:03:04.421+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"172.17.0.4:33350","uuid":"535a26aa-f902-43b3-9865-b9a75a9ddbd4","connectionId":8,"connectionCount":1}}""
[service:mongors-registry.gitlab.com__sunnyatticsoftware__mongodb-rs-registry.gitlab.com-sunnyatticsoftware-mongodb-rs] 2023-11-02T10:03:04.427158992Z 2023-11-02T10:03:04.427Z MongoMS:MongoInstance Mongo[27017]: stdoutHandler: ""{"t":{"$date":"2023-11-02T10:03:04.426+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn8","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"172.17.0.4:33350","client":"conn8","doc":{"application":{"name":"mongosh 2.0.2"},"driver":{"name":"nodejs|mongosh","version":"6.0.0|2.0.2"},"platform":"Node.js v20.8.1, LE","os":{"name":"linux","architecture":"x64","version":"5.4.109+","type":"Linux"}}}}""
[service:mongors-registry.gitlab.com__sunnyatticsoftware__mongodb-rs-registry.gitlab.com-sunnyatticsoftware-mongodb-rs] 2023-11-02T10:03:04.433126958Z 2023-11-02T10:03:04.432Z MongoMS:MongoInstance Mongo[27017]: stdoutHandler: ""{"t":{"$date":"2023-11-02T10:03:04.432+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn8","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"172.17.0.4:33350","uuid":"535a26aa-f902-43b3-9865-b9a75a9ddbd4","connectionId":8,"connectionCount":0}}""
MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Also adding a trailing slash in connection string before the parameters (i.e: `mongodb://mongors:27017/?replicaSet=rs0`) does not make any difference.

```
$ mongosh "mongodb://mongors:27017/?replicaSet=rs0" --quiet --eval "db.runCommand({ hello: 1 })" || exit 1
[service:registry.gitlab.com-sunnyatticsoftware-mongodb-rs-mongors-registry.gitlab.com__sunnyatticsoftware__mongodb-rs] 2023-11-02T10:06:19.703057492Z 2023-11-02T10:06:19.702Z MongoMS:MongoInstance Mongo[27017]: stdoutHandler: ""{"t":{"$date":"2023-11-02T10:06:19.702+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"172.17.0.4:37438","uuid":"25eda74c-bdee-43dd-9b5b-e10f7edfdaf7","connectionId":9,"connectionCount":1}}""
[service:registry.gitlab.com-sunnyatticsoftware-mongodb-rs-mongors-registry.gitlab.com__sunnyatticsoftware__mongodb-rs] 2023-11-02T10:06:19.706469535Z 2023-11-02T10:06:19.706Z MongoMS:MongoInstance Mongo[27017]: stdoutHandler: ""{"t":{"$date":"2023-11-02T10:06:19.706+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn9","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"172.17.0.4:37438","client":"conn9","doc":{"application":{"name":"mongosh 2.0.2"},"driver":{"name":"nodejs|mongosh","version":"6.0.0|2.0.2"},"platform":"Node.js v20.8.1, LE","os":{"name":"linux","architecture":"x64","version":"5.4.109+","type":"Linux"}}}}""
[service:registry.gitlab.com-sunnyatticsoftware-mongodb-rs-mongors-registry.gitlab.com__sunnyatticsoftware__mongodb-rs] 2023-11-02T10:06:19.712527412Z 2023-11-02T10:06:19.712Z MongoMS:MongoInstance Mongo[27017]: stdoutHandler: ""{"t":{"$date":"2023-11-02T10:06:19.712+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn9","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"172.17.0.4:37438","uuid":"25eda74c-bdee-43dd-9b5b-e10f7edfdaf7","connectionId":9,"connectionCount":0}}""
MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
```

Comment: idk particular CI/CD details, but the timeout error says that the driver can't connect to mongo server, usually it happens because the server has not been launched

Comment: Can you provide your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file and the whole job log?

Comment: @AdamMarshall see UPDATE 1 where I leave mongo C# driver out of the picture and I test connectivity with mongosh. When connecting to hostname/alias without specifying replicaSet it works well, but as soon as I specify replicaSet in  connection string it won't connect.

Comment: That's definitely strange. To me it looks like you might get more luck answering this question if you edit your title and reword some of the body. Since the connection does work fine without `?replicaSet=rs0`, to me that suggests everything on the GitLab side is working correctly, so maybe it's more of a Mongo or Docker question.

Comment: what the result of `{ hello : 1 }` instead `{ ping : 1 }`?

Comment: @dododo same thing, see update 3 with `{hello:1}` and also with the connection string adding a slash between host and parameters `mongodb://mongors:27017/?replicaSet=rs0`

Comment: you didn't specify rs name based on this `Connect mongosh to mongodb://mongors:27017`

Comment: @dododo I did, my pipeline runs both commands in the same CI/CD pipeline `Connect mongosh to mongodb://mongors:27017` which succeeds and `Connect mongosh to mongodb://mongors:27017?replicaSet=rs0` which fails, to show the difference, as described.